# Setting Text Value From External Class

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am attempting to modify a control on the applications startup form from a separate class that is instantiated from a button's event handler in the startup form.

This is the click listener in the main form:

```
Sub Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim changer As New Changer()
    changer.dochange

End Sub
```

This is the class Changer:

```
Public Class Changer
Sub dochange
    'ignore this part
    Dim window As Form1
    window = New Form1()
    window.Show

          'this is where i have a problem:
    Dim bunz As MainForm
    bunz = New MainForm()
    bunz.label1.Text = "sometext"
End Sub
 End Class
```

I've even set up my label1 so that it is public, but the text still won't change. What is wrong?

Comment: You are never showing your `bunz` form, is this code example complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because you are creating a second Mainform and changing the label text on the second one not the original. What you need to do is create an event for your Changer Class and subscribe to it in your MainForm and use that to change the Text of your label

**MainText**

```
Public Class MainForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim changer As New Changer()
        AddHandler changer.ChangeText, AddressOf ChangeTextHandler
        changer.dochange()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeTextHandler(value As String)
        Label1.Text = value
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Changer Class**

```
Public Class Changer
    Public Event ChangeText(value As String)
    Sub dochange()
        'ignore this part
        Dim window As Form1
        window = New Form1()
        window.Show()
        RaiseEvent ChangeText("SomeText")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm new to VB and I was hoping to only have an object created in the mouse listener, rather than a handler and teh object. But I guess that's the way VB is.

Comment: @javac It is good practice to do it this way in C# and VB.Net, a child should not have knowledge of the internals of the parent. If you want you could create a property on the parent that sets the label then pass the parent into the constructor of your changer class, then you can set the property.

Answer (score 1):

The below code example should work. In VB you don't always need to explicitly declare or have a reference to the form you are trying to modify. If it's been opened as the main form or opened using the Shared ShowDialog method then you can reference Label1 in this case as a shared property of the form. There is no need to create a separate instance.

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim changer As New Changer()
        changer.dochange()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Changer
    Sub dochange()
        'ignore this part
        Dim window As Form1
        window = New Form1()
        window.Show()

        'this is where i have a problem:
        MainForm.Label1.Text = "sometext"
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above is in two separate files one the MainForm.vb file that was created from Visual Studio by adding a Windows Form and the other by adding a Class.

Comment: Thanks. Right now it opens both windows, and it opens a new instance of the form and does display "sometext". But how can i change the first instance?

Comment: Is it a Windows Forms Application and MainForm is the form you are opening at application start? Also, is the Button1Click event handler in the MainForm or in a secondary form?

Comment: The button click is in the main form which also has the button. Within the button click is a new instance of the class changer is made and a method (dochange) is called. I want dochange to open up a new window (Form1 is the window and it successfully opens it) but I want it to also change the label text in the first form to "sometext"

Answer (score 1):

This was just what I was looking for. I wanted to clear a status strip label on a formn from another class. In the form I added AddHandler otherClass.ChangeText, AddressOf ChangeTextHandler and the sub  ChangeTextHandler. In the otherClass I did  RaiseEvent ChangeText(" ") and it worked. Thank You! Thank You! One thing, I kept getting a warmning about access to shared ... would be ignored. I defined the Event like  Public Shared Event ChangeText(value As String) and no more issues. Happy there are some very brilliant people here.